# Write jQuery inside product template in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to fetch variant id of product in Shopify and pass it to jQuery. But I'm unable to write script in (Sections/product-template.liquid).
Browser gives error of **'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'**

I've written this code at the end of **product-template.liquid**.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($)
{
    $current_variant_id = {{ product.selected_variant.id }};
    $interval = setInterval(function()
    {
       if( $( '.product-single__thumbnail-item.slick-slide.slick-active.is-active' ).length > 0 )
       {
           if( !($( '.product-single__thumbnail-item[data-variant="'+$current_variant_id+'"]' ).hasClass('is-active')) )
           {
               $( '.product-single__thumbnail-item.slick-slide.slick-active.is-active' ).removeClass('is-active');
               $( '.product-single__thumbnail-item[data-variant="'+$current_variant_id+'"]' ).addClass('is-active');
           }
           clearInterval( $interval );
       }
    },1);
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what order are you loading your scripts?

Comment: I'm writing this script in .liquid file. Does order matters here? Cause it'd work perfectly in Wordpress!

Comment: Check jQuery is being loaded before your script or added before it...

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you are not using jQuery on your store website. The simplest way is edit your `theme.liquid` to include jQuery for every page. Just put a `script` tag below right before `</head>` tag is ok:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is for you to make sure your Javascript library is loaded in theme.liquid, in the head element. That ensures you can use your $ variable from that library.